# What does issueFieldMatch() do?

Tags: jira, jql

I got this query:

```
project = LSN AND  issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("  ", labels, commited) AND issuetype in (CR, PR) AND Stopper not in ("Not a Stopper ") AND status not in (closed)
```

And I'm not sure what `issueFunction` does.

Answer (score 0):

`issueFunction` is provided by the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview) app.

It allows you to use custom functions provided by Script Runner in your JQL queries. Ie. `hasComments`, `hasAttachments`, `issueFieldMatch` etc.. You can also implement your own custom JQL functions using Groovy scripts.

More details are available in the Script Runner [documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work in the following way to find partial prefix of suffix in a label behavior field.

```
project = PRJ AND issueFunction in issueFieldMatch("labels is not EMPTY", labels, "^.ABC")
```

**Syntax**

- ^.THING (begins with)
- THING.$ (ends with)

This appears to be working.